# Rotate 3d AR object 360 degree using touch with ARToolkit ios+sdk

Tags: ios, iphone, augmented-reality, artoolkit, 3d-model

I am using ARToolKit iOS SDK for rendering 3D model in my augmented reality project. Now through this sdk I have rendered 3D model but I am not able to rotate 360 it by touch so please help me to rotate my model.

Answer (score 1):

Please use setLocalPosePositionX method is availble in VEObject class to rotate 3D model in ARToolKit SDK.

Answer (score 1):

You can detect touch in **“ARView.m”** file so implement touch delegates in that class and get touch coordinates and send to **“VEObject.m”** class via **NSNotification** and then call **“setLocalPosePositionX”** method to rotate the model

Comment: can you show me some code how we can achieve ? i tried it but not working